# nginx print wrong milliseconds in timestamp

Tags: java, nginx, jodatime

Nginx log timestamp is `2016-09-11 14:29:22.987` or `2016-09-11 14:29:22.94` or `2016-09-11 14:29:22.4`

Buf after joda time format parsed result is `2016-09-11 14:29:22.987`, `2016-09-11 14:29:22.940`, `2016-09-11 14:29:22.400` with pattern "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"

expect results are `2016-09-11 14:29:22.987`, `2016-09-11 14:29:22.094`, `2016-09-11 14:29:22.004`

in Nginx log `2016-09-11 14:29:22.1` is before `2016-09-11 14:29:22.10` which also before `2016-09-11 14:29:22.100`, so I think nginx log is mean `2016-09-11 14:29:22.001` and `2016-09-11 14:29:22.010`

How to fix to let nginx print `2016-09-11 14:29:22.1` as `2016-09-11 14:29:22.001`?
Thanks

Comment: No, Joda-Time is correct. ".4" must be same as ".400", not ".004". That is simple math.

Comment: So you mean 2016-09-11 14:29:22.4 is later then 2016-09-11 14:29:22.39 and also later then 2016-09-11 14:29:22.389?

Comment: But why the log 2016-09-11 14:29:22.4 is before 2016-09-11 14:29:22.39 in Nginx access log?

Comment: Then you seem to have found a bug in Nginx :-(